# JavaFx - Set Labeltext while joining on new Pane

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to change the Labeltext of the Pane before joining on this Pane.

Situation:

```java
    @FXML
    javafx.scene.control.Label difficultLabel;
    private final GameController game = new GameControllerImpl();
```

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("resources/HomeMenuPane.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    @FXML
    public void gameEasy(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("GamePane Difficult 1");
        Parent GamePane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("resources/GamePane.fxml"));
        app.changePane(gameEasyButton, GamePane);
        game.setup(1);
        difficultLabel.setText("Difficult: 1");
    }

    @FXML
    public void gameMiddle(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("GamePane Difficult 2");
        Parent GamePane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("resources/GamePane.fxml"));
        app.changePane(gameMiddleButton, GamePane);
        game.setup(2);
        difficultLabel.setText("Difficult: 1");
    }

    @FXML
    public void gameHeavy(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("GamePane Difficult 3");
        Parent GamePane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("resources/GamePane.fxml"));
        app.changePane(gameHeavyButton, GamePane);
        game.setup(3);
        difficultLabel.setText("Difficult: 1");
    }
```

Console error output:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.Label.setText(String)" because "this.difficultLabel" is null
    at simonMemory/wiss.sm.app.App.gameEasy(App.java:110)
```

By reading the error output i can tell that the label is in that moment null. Is there a way to wait for the label get loaded ? Any suggestion?

Comment: looks like your fxml  controller class is the same class with main() method and the same who extends Application

Comment: try in your `start()` method: `difficultLabel = new Label("sometext");`

Comment: @GiovanniContreras  does that matter? ... i have not worked with javafx for years ':D

Comment: in OOP a new Label object will not point to the original fxml object

Comment: The `@FXML`-annotated fields will only be initialised in the controller. They won’t be initialised in the `Application ` instance on which `start()` is invoked.

Comment: @user3192295 It makes things harder to reason about. When launched normally, the JavaFX framework will create an instance of the `Application` implementation for you. But if that class is also functioning as an FXML controller, then by default the `FXMLLoader` will create a separate instance for its purposes. Now you have two instances, neither of which you explicitly created. This can be confusing, especially for beginners, as now some fields are `null` only "some of the time". That's why it's discouraged to have the `Application` implementation and FXML controller be the same class.

Comment: There is a comment “try in your start() method: difficultLabel = new Label("sometext");” -> do not try that if the code was supposed to be injected by FXML.  FXML injected values should not be set to new values.  Even if you did that and it appeared to work this would just mask your underlying issues.

Comment: @all, it makes absolute sense the fxml label being injected and thus not create it; I just thought about getting the nullpointerexept. out of the way first,.. thanks for the clarification